# Как игнорировать значение родителя в css

Tags: html, css

На странице есть статья обернутая в тег `p` у данного тега стоит `opacity: 0.8`, из админки в тег `p` вставляется картинка, из-за того что в родителе есть прозрачность она применяется к картинке. Как указать картинке `opcity: 1`?

```css
div {
  max-width: 70%;
}

p img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

p {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Песня "All The Things She Said" (в русском варианте - "Я сошла с ума") полифигурно имитирует ревер. Адажио, так или иначе, mezzo forte имеет сет. Пласт, и это особенно заметно у Чарли Паркера или Джона Колтрейна, просветляет серийный гипнотический рифф.</p>
  <p><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532842-98d0fd5ebc1a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80" alt=""></p>
  <p>Кризис жанра полифигурно образует контрапункт контрастных фактур. Трехчастная фактурная форма, согласно традиционным представлениям, полифигурно дает нечетный канал. Пуантилизм, зародившийся в музыкальных микроформах начала ХХ столетия, нашел далекую
    историческую параллель в лице средневекового гокета, однако субтехника полифигурно иллюстрирует структурный сет.
    <a href="">Внутридискретное</a> арпеджио трансформирует мнимотакт.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если стоит задача - не трогая разметку, сделать полупрозрачный текст - то, можно именно ему и задавать прозрачность:

```css
div { max-width: 70%; }

p img { max-width: 100%; }

p, p *:not(img) {
  color: rgba(0 0 0 / 0.4);
  transition: color .5s ease;
}
p:hover, p:hover *:not(img) {
  color: rgba(0 0 0 / 1);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Песня "All The Things She Said" (в русском варианте - "Я сошла с ума") полифигурно имитирует ревер. Адажио, так или иначе, mezzo forte имеет сет. Пласт, и это особенно заметно у Чарли Паркера или Джона Колтрейна, просветляет серийный гипнотический рифф.</p>
  <p><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532842-98d0fd5ebc1a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80" alt=""></p>
  <p>Кризис жанра полифигурно образует контрапункт контрастных фактур. Трехчастная фактурная форма, согласно традиционным представлениям, полифигурно дает нечетный канал. Пуантилизм, зародившийся в музыкальных микроформах начала ХХ столетия, нашел далекую
    историческую параллель в лице средневекового гокета, однако субтехника полифигурно иллюстрирует структурный сет.
    <a href="">Внутридискретное</a> арпеджио трансформирует мнимотакт.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: А давно поддерживается запись `rgba(0 0 0 / 0.4)`?

Comment: @CbIPoK2513: нет, недавно (пока черновик, но в нём уже называют устаревшим разделение значений запятыми) - https://drafts.csswg.org/css-color/#rgb-functions

Comment: @CbIPoK2513: на сайте Мозиллы это назывыают "пробельный синтаксис в функциональной нотации" - https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/color_value

Comment: Спасибо за решение!

Comment: @molink: я думаю, что лучше будет заменить на `color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);`, всё таки. На всякий случай :-)

Answer (score 2):

Никак. В любом случае свойство `opacity` будет работать на все дочерние элементы. Разместите тег `img` вне тега `p`, чтобы к нему не применялось значение opacity

Comment: а разве z-index тут не поможет?

Comment: @АнтонКравцов z-index никак не меняет отношение `ребёнок <--> родитель` =)